# vb.net get name of currentlie loading Excel file during the loade

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto, ribbon

I am creating a VSTO add in for Excel with an extensive collection of subs. These are controlled via the buttons of a RibbonBar. For reasons not all buttons should be shown to every user. I currently solve this problem by opening and reading an Excel file "UserID" with the corresponding entries when loading the ribbonbar. Here comes my problem. if Excel is opened via the icon, i.e. no specific file, then an empty window remains after closing the "UserID" file via code. I tried to check if a workbook is open and if not just open a blank one but that always opens a workbook even if a specific xlsx is opened. Currently my code is running in ribbon.vb. My question, how can I check if excel is currently opened by icon or by xlsx? or are ther other options to try? Let me say that there is no possibility to use a real database. It must be done via VSTO or an Excel file.

Comment: I'm wondering if perhaps you need to run your code in a different event handler. Have you seen [Access a document when the Office application starts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/programming-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019#AccessingDocuments)?

Comment: Slight different approach, to me seems a little off to be using a xlsx file to store the settings.  Might I suggest using something other.  Many file types/tools are available for this (xml, json, ini....)

Comment: I've used SQL Server CE for instances like this. Also Active Directory groups can be used.

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments. I have now changed the concept. I will still keep the excel file but only for the person who needs to manage the users. I will also change the User.xlsx in a vsto project and add code that will create or update an xml file with all the data. And the big add-in will check the user information from the xml file and will not need to open the excel file. the user.xlsx will push and pull data from the xml file every time it is used. I think this will work.